# a library for spl_autoload?

Tags: php

I wonder if there is any library for `spl_autoload` where one can just set all the folders and it will take care of loading them correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Frameworks such as Zend Framework have components you can use (I mention ZF because it is loosely coupled) which wrap spl_autoload. But my experience is that if that's all the functionality you want to use, it's probably easier/quicker/lighter to write your own autoload function and register it.